# How to set an authorization header in swagger to authenticate TIBCO AMX BPM rest services?

Tags: rest, tibco, swagger-editor

Hi after reading quite a number of answers on how to set the authorization header in swagger I am still facing an issue trying to authenticate the TIBCO AMX BPM rest services using swagger.

I know that there is no issue with the user name or password that have been provided to me as I'm able to invoke this rest api from the soapui tool.

Please advise on how I can go about authenticating this API in Swagger editor.

[screenshot of the swagger editor screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms6qe.png)
[SoapUI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYldv.png)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: what type of authentication? oauth, basic etc?

Comment: @Rao it is basic auth that I'm trying at the moment.